# Explain meaning of this quote in Black Hawk Down

Tags: dialogue, black-hawk-down

Before the Battle of Mogadishu, during a dinner scene, Steele comes up to Hoot and asks him what's going on.

Hoot replies: "Oh, just some aerial target practice, sir. Didn't want to leave it behind."

What is he referring to? It isn't his weapon, because Steele replies with: "I'm talking about your weapon."

Answer (score 8):

In case you missed it, the scene starts with the troops having an impromptu barbecue with the wild boar killed by Hoot.

Hence, the "aerial practice" Hoot is referring to is the act of killing the beast.

"Didn't want to leave it behind" is for the dead animal itself.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to CinCout's answer; the follow on sentence

> I'm talking about your weapon...

leads onto Hoot (and the audience) realising that Steele is actually asking why Hoot is walking around with his rifle's safety off - a big no-no on the base unless (possibly even if) on guard duty). Hoot replies

> this is my safety, sir.

Referring to his finger. Here's the clip in question: